# php mysql make checkboxes checked

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, foreach, checked

I am trying to code a php script that automaticly selects the selected users (checkboxes)
I don't know what it is i am missing, maybe you guys can help out. What i am trying is:

```
$get_users = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_type='5' AND user_id_parent='". get_uid() ."'");

$get_checkedusers = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM modules_users_availability WHERE module_id='". $mid ."' AND shopid='". get_uid() ."'
");

while ($row = $getcheckedusers->fetch_assoc()) {
     $chosenCategory[] = $row['userid'];                    
}

while($users = $getusers->fetch_assoc()){
     foreach($chosenCategory as $chosencategories){
          if($users['user_id'] == $chosenCategory){
               echo $checked = "checked";                       
          }                 
     }?>

<tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" <?php echo $selected; ?> name="access[]" value="<?php echo $users['user_id']; ?>" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $users['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $users['email']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

My problem is that i can't use the getcheckedusers array correctly in getusers while.
It returns trible result if there is 3 users, and double result if here is 2. Maybe i'm missing something? :)

Comment: you missed posting the rest of your code that is related to the above code.

Comment: Please provide your sql statements to select the checkedusers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($users = $getusers->fetch_assoc()){
     $checked="";
      if(in_array($users['user_id'],$chosenCategory)){
           $checked = "checked";                       

     }?>

<tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" <?php echo $checked; ?> name="access[]" value="<?php echo $users['user_id']; ?>" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $users['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $users['email']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I have changed my original post a little. Please review if you have the time :)

Comment: this should work,there is no selected variable declared in the loop

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for you help, i will definitely check up on in_array :)

Answer (score 0):

If condition is wrong.. I hope it should like this

```
if ($users['user_id'] == $chosencategories) {}
```